# impressionist does not log the Rails 4 session value into session_hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
impressionist(@object, nil, unique: [:session_hash])
```

Calling impressionist() inserts the record first time, later on every request it says **Record Already Exist** because it always find **Nil value for session_hash**. it looks it does not log the rails-4 session value into "session_hash".

I'm using Rails 4.1.6, ruby 2.1.3p242 and impressionist (1.5.1)

Any help on this ?

Comment: How did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're describing is the same as mine and I found the solution under this open issue on the git repo.

https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/177

You have to override the session hash method for your project to initialise the session before making a request for the id.

```
ImpressionistController::InstanceMethods.class_eval do 
  def session_hash
    session[:init] = true
    request.session.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue. I ended up using a conditional statement checking whether the session_hash exists.

```
if session_hash.blank?
  impressionist(@object)
else
  impressionist(@object, nil, unique: [:session_hash])
end
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue correctly. The problem is with the Impressionist gem not using the right session call.